# GH cli - how to get current repo?

Tags: github, repo, github-cli

Use GitHub cli (gh), how do I get a current repo name?

I can get a listing of the repos I have but how do I get the current repo?

Comment: What do you mean with "Current repo"?

Answer (score 11):

To get the name of the repo in the curernt working directory, run

```sh
gh repo view --json name -q ".name"
```

This extracts the name of the repo from the command that lists information about the repo in the current directory, and extracts the actual name from the JSON output. For instance, if you were in the working directory for the repo with a URL of http://github.com/rust-lang/rust, the output would be `rust`.

Comment: I just stumbled across the same problem. While your solution works, it does an API request that should not be required. However, I didn't find a way to do it without the API request either.

Comment: If you'd like the fullname you can also use `gh repo view --json nameWithOwner -q ".nameWithOwner"`

Answer (score 0):

In github actions, there are environment variables that provide this information.  In particular:

- `GITHUB_REPOSITORY` The owner and repository name. For example, `octocat/Hello-World`.
- `GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER` The repository owner's name. For example, `octocat`.

From this you can get the name without the owner:

- `${GITHUB_REPOSITORY#$GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER/}`  The repository name. For example, `Hello-World`

For a full list of variables, see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables